# Trying to reverse a string in C++ but getting the same string back

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, reverse

I get the same string back when I try to reverse it in C++.

I read that recursion is a good way to reverse things. I tried to implement a recursive algorithm by returning the first character of the string and calling the same function with the first character removed until the string has a size of 1. My first function removes the first character of the string and the second function reverses it:

```
string deleteFirstElement(string input) {

    if (input.size() == 1) {
        return input;
    }

    // This loop brings the first element to the last position
    for (int i = 0; i < input.size()-1; i++) { 
        char temp;
        temp = input.at(i);
        input.at(i) = input.at(i+1);
        input.at(i + 1) = temp;
    }

    input.pop_back();   // Delete last element of the string
    return input;
}

string reverseit(string input) {
    if (input.size() == 1) {
        return input;
    }
    else {
        return input.at(0) + reverseit(deleteFirstElement(input));
    }
}
```

But why do I get the same string back and no reverse?

Comment: `input.at(input.at(0))`?

Comment: @Sneftel Ouch.. I don't know why I wrote that, it should rather be input.at(0). This change removes the out_of_range error but now I get the same string back which I put into the function, no reversion at all :p Will edit my question now.

Comment: It's also just wrong. Is the reverse of "abc" equal to "a" plus the reverse of "bc"? And should deleteFirstElement("a") return "a"?

Comment: Instead of that complicated loop to manually delete the first element, `input.erase(input.begin());` would have done the job.

Comment: If the requirement is "reverse a string", it's mostly done for you: `std::string reversed(input.rbegin(), input.rend());`

Comment: @Caleth It's no homework >.< I'm only trying to do things recursively because I want understand it better the recursion.

Comment: You want to understand recursion better by using it to solve a task where recursion is unsuited?

Comment: the crux is that to understand recursion you first need to understand recursion

Comment: @user463035818 nonono. for recursion you need a stopping condition.

Comment: Just FYI [`std::reverse`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/reverse) already exists, but likely you have to do this yourself for a homework assignment

Comment: @AndyG And again, this is no homework. If it was homework and I was desperately looking for a working solution, I would just have googled one and copy pasted it within 2 minutes. I asked this question because I didn't understand why MY solution didn't work.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You get the same string back because you build the same string again.
Using the example of "ABC" you'll see what the function does:

reverseit("ABC") returns 'A' + reverseit("BC")
reverseit("BC") returns 'B' + reverseit("C")
reverseit("C") returns 'C'

You'd want

```
char firstChar = input.at(0);
return  reverseit(deleteFirstElement(input)) + firstChar;
```

But really you should be looking into another solution. Recursion

- reduces readability
- is slow
- uses lots of stack memory
- easily creates hard to debug endless loops

in general it should be avoided if possible. Some solutions are really elegant with it, to be sure, but loops are almost always faster.

Answer (score 3):

change the else part from this

```
  string reverseit(string input) {
        if (input.size() == 1) {
            return input;
        }
        else {
            return input.at(0) + reverseit(deleteFirstElement(input));
        }
    }
```

to this

```
string reverseit(string input) {
    if (input.size() == 1) {
        return input;
    }
    else {
        return reverseit(deleteFirstElement(input))+ input.at(0);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Recursion is not the easy way to reverse things.

Here is the easy way:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string s { "hello" };

    reverse(s.begin(), s.end());

    cout << s << endl;
}
```

Here is a recusive solution. It works but is much less reasonable and efficient.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

string recursiveReverse(string value, string accum = "")
{
    if(value.size() == 0)
    {
        return accum;
    }
    else
    {
        accum += value.back();
        value.pop_back();
        return recursiveReverse(value, accum);
    }
}

int main()
{
    string s { "hello" };

    s = recursiveReverse(s);

    cout << s << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have [boost](/questions/tagged/boost), this problem basicly boils down:

```
string reverseit(string input) {
  string result(input);
  boost::range::reverse(result);
  return result;
}
```

Without [boost](/questions/tagged/boost), you may instead use:

```
std::reverse(result.begin(), result.end());
```

As noted, recursion reduced readability of your program and should be reserved for rare cases (usually where another solution is just more complicated).

Comment: OP said he wants to learn recursion. suggesting a solution without recursion doesn't seem like an answer to me. Also including boost just for reversing an array seems overkill

Comment: @FalcoGer I mainly added this answer as an addition for completeness and other users (I understand the OP might very well not have boost) to show how it can be done IF you have boost (already).