# A recursive function that retrieves characters and returns in reverse order c++

Tags: c++, recursion

I have a homework with which I cannot cope.
"Write a recursive function that retrieves characters from the user until it encounters an star and returns a string of user-entered characters (without an star - *) in reverse order than they were entered."

I tried to write a code that gets characters until the star appears, but I do not know how to display the characters in reverse.

> **Solution**

```
string recursiveReverse()
{
    cout << "Enter a new character" << endl;
    char text;
    cin >> text;

    if(text == '*')
        return std::string();
    else
        recursiveReverse();
        cout << text;
}
```

Comment: From your snippet, it seems you misinterpreted the question. Do user input in separate loop (without recursion).

Comment: @seccpur I don’t think you’re right.

Comment: This may be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55043688/trying-to-reverse-a-string-in-c-but-getting-the-same-string-back/55044586#55044586

Comment: You're supposed to return a *string* not one character. If you have a `std::string`, how do you append a character to that string? What would happen if you, for example, did something like `funct() + some_character` (assuming that `funct` returns a `std::string`)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two stumbling blocks in what you’ve shown us:

1. Your function takes an argument; why? Nothing in the problem description suggests doing so.
2. Your function returns `char` rather than `std::string` (as requested).

If you adapt these two points you end up with the following function signature<sup>1</sup>:

```
std::string magic();
```

Now, how to implement this function? Well, the problem description hints at it:

- read a single character
- if the character is `'*'`, return (an empty string) immediately
- otherwise, recursively call the function and concatenate the current character to its return value.

---

<sup>1</sup> This is the intuitive, naïve solution. There’s a better solution, which requires a changed signature. But this probably isn’t asked here and the reason *why* that signature is better isn’t trivial to explain.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you make the function return type void, when you encounter * you just return.
and you call the function recursively without putting a return before your recursive call
and then you print the character that you got and then you return.

Comment: This would work, except the assignment explicitly asks for the result to be *returned*.